# React drag and drop and sortable component

Tags: reactjs, sorting, drag-and-drop

I am trying to create dropable zone to add images to my application. I also want those images, once added, to be sortable by dragging them and reordering them in grid type of zone.

I have implemented react-dropzone-component which is great. The problem now is to be able to select the images added into the dropzone and drag them to reorder them as desired.

```
return (
      <Reorder
        reorderId="my-list" // Unique ID that is used internally to track this list (required)
        reorderGroup="reorder-group" // A group ID that allows items to be dragged between lists of the same group (optional)
        // getRef={this.storeRef.bind(this)} // Function that is passed a reference to the root node when mounted (optional)
        component="div" // Tag name or Component to be used for the wrapping element (optional), defaults to 'div'
        placeholderClassName="placeholder" // Class name to be applied to placeholder elements (optional), defaults to 'placeholder'
        draggedClassName="dragged" // Class name to be applied to dragged elements (optional), defaults to 'dragged'
        // lock="horizontal" // Lock the dragging direction (optional): vertical, horizontal (do not use with groups)
        holdTime={500} // Default hold time before dragging begins (mouse & touch) (optional), defaults to 0
        touchHoldTime={500} // Hold time before dragging begins on touch devices (optional), defaults to holdTime
        mouseHoldTime={0} // Hold time before dragging begins with mouse (optional), defaults to holdTime
        onReorder={this.onReorder.bind(this)} // Callback when an item is dropped (you will need this to update your state)
        autoScroll={true} // Enable auto-scrolling when the pointer is close to the edge of the Reorder component (optional), defaults to true
        disabled={false} // Disable reordering (optional), defaults to false
        disableContextMenus={true} // Disable context menus when holding on touch devices (optional), defaults to true
        placeholder={
          <div className="custom-placeholder" /> // Custom placeholder element (optional), defaults to clone of dragged element
        }
      >
        <DropzoneComponent
          config={config}
          eventHandlers={eventHandlers}
          djsConfig={djsConfig}
        />

      </Reorder>
```

There are some great components called react-sortable-hoc or react-reorder but I can't integrate it since this component needs to have access to any single image added during. I only have access to the higher Dropzone component but not its children.

Anyone has managed to achieve this in any other way ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4eBQ.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you will need it now or not. I came across this exact usecase and used react-drag-sortable (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-drag-sortable) for sorting using drag and drop in react-dropzone

```
//import component
import DragSortableList from 'react-drag-sortable';

//function to be called in every sort
onSort = (sortedList,dropEvent) => {
// arrange items according to events
let _sortedList = []
for (let i = 0; i<sortedList.length ; i++) {
  _sortedList.push(
    images.find((item)=>{
      if (item.key === sortedList[i].content.key) {
        item['sort'] = i+1;
        return item;
      }
    })
  )
}
this.setState({sortedList: [..._sortedList]})
};

// component
 <Dropzone
      ref={node => {
        this.dropzoneRef = node;
     }}
     onDrop={this.onDrop}
 >
  <DragSortableList
    items={this.state.sortedList}
    dropBackTransitionDuration={0.3}
    onSort={onSort}
    placeholder: <div className={`placeholderContent`}>DROP HERE</div>
    type: 'grid'
  />
 </Dropzone>
```